# On ng-click its loading different controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am Working on profile page , On click on profile i am navigating to profile.html page and profilectrl, but when i click not able to load  profilectrl its loading builderctrl, I used $location.path. Here is my code.

This is My click Function

```
$scope.profile=function(){
      $location.path("/profile");

    }
```

Here is my Routing Structure

```
sidemenu.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/builders/:id', {
            templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
            controller: 'buildersCtrl'
            })
        .when('/builders/:id/property/:property_id', {
            templateUrl: '../view/property-details.html',
            controller: 'unitTypeCtrl'
        })

        .when('/property/:property_id', {
            templateUrl: '../view/property-details.html',
            controller: 'unitTypeCtrl'
        })

         .when('/profile/', {      
            templateUrl: '../view/profile.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })
```

}])

Comment: In your routing you have mentioned '/profile/', but in $location it was '/profile'. Try adding '/' at the end, then check and post your comments

Comment: it worked by keeping '/profile in first line of $routeProvider i.e before '/builders' . it worked to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is worked by changing the   $routeProvider . Code is as below.

```
sidemenu.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

         .when('/profile', {        
            templateUrl: '../view/profile.html',
            controller: 'profileCtrl'
        })

        .when('/builders/:id', {
            templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
            controller: 'buildersCtrl'
            })
        .when('/builders/:id/property/:property_id', {
            templateUrl: '../view/property-details.html',
            controller: 'unitTypeCtrl'
        })

        .when('/property/:property_id', {
            templateUrl: '../view/property-details.html',
            controller: 'unitTypeCtrl'
        })

        .when('/filterate/:query',{
            templateUrl: '../template/listpagefilter.html',
            controller: 'buildersCtrl'
        })

}])
```